# Posting to a page containing custom module from external site gives '403 Forbidden'

Tags: ee2, module

I have a template containing a tag from a custom module that processes POST'd data from an external site, but when the page is called it responds with a 403 error (so the logs from the external site tell me anyway).

If I remove the tag, the page will display, but with the tag in it I get an empty page.

Changing the request to a GET is not an option.

EE : v2.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, is really not too much info you provide to us (what EE version, what module etc.). But I can suggest that it is results of [Cross-site Request Forgery protection](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/guidelines/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery). Possible you do not provide csrf_token/xid with your POST.

Just for test - try to disable it in config.php

```
$config['secure_forms'] = 'n'; // for EE <2.8
$config['disable_csrf_protection'] = 'y'; // for EE >=2.8
```

It is also good to know what exactly was on the page, not just header data. Because it can be EE 403 error because of protection, but it can be server info also. For example - do you have mod_security on server? What status of SecFilterEngine?

Comment: config.php has this: `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE`, I assume that means it's disabled already.

Comment: ok, I see your ee version now - try to add $config['secure_forms'] = 'n'; into you config for test.

Comment: I also add additional info into post.

Comment: I added `$config['secure_forms'] = 'n';` it didn't help though

Comment: mod_security is installed on my server and it caused a different issue recently, so it is now turned off.

Comment: did you check what error you have on page - ee or server? You can try it here - http://demo-ee.com/examples/view/test-form-to-post-data-on-server

Comment: hmmm, strangely, even though I have changed nothing, it seems to be working now, I suspect my Hosting hadn't fully turned off mod_sec.